# Why must I return a function when calling api, but not when calling a view controller in express (KeystoneJs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, keystonejs

In express, my code for views must follow this format (I'm using keystonejs CMS as well):

```
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
      // view code
}
```

However, when I'm creating an api that returns json, I must return a function:

```
exports = module.exports = function() {
    return function(req, res) {
        // api code
    }
}
```

I can call both endpoints the same way via a normal route, so why do I have to return a function in the api, but not in the view code?

Comment: Are you using any infrastructure other than express? You may want to look into the program that will import your function to see how it differs there.

Comment: @vityavv Actually yes. I'm using keystoneCMS. Do you think this is some behavior specific to keystone?

Comment: This is almost definitely specific to keystone, you should totally specify that in your question :)

Comment: @vityavv I edited it in. I honestly didn't think this would be specific to keystone!

Comment: @vityavv Turns out it wasn't keystone after all. Just had to remove () when calling the route. Simply overlooked it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was not specific to keystone. My route for the api was calling the controller the same way I'd call it on a post that accepts a parameter.

Route for post view:

```
app.post('/home/:imgtype', routes.api.imgloader.uploadProfileImg(param));
```

Route for api that included form data in http body:

```
app.post('/postblurt', routes.api.blurtapi.postBlurt());
```

So all I had to do was remove the (), which executes function and expects return value.

```
app.post('/postblurt', routes.api.blurtapi.postBlurt);
```

A simple thing I overlooked: when a route is called with a param you must then return function.